# Can a magician cast a spell in water?

Tags: talmud-gemara, water, weather, sorcery-magic-kishuf, maseches-sanhedrin

The power of magicians and magic, the Talmud speaks plenty about.

One such example is that of Ze'iri and the donkey, in Sanhedrin 67:

> זעירי איקלע לאלכסנדריא של מצרים זבן חמרא כי מטא לאשקוייה מיא פשר וקם גמלא דוסקניתא אמרו ליה אי לאו זעירי את לא הוה מהדרינן לך מי איכא דזבין מידי הכא ולא בדיק ליה אמיא

Basically, Zi'iri goes to Alexandra, Egypt and he buys a donkey that when he goes to give it drink (water), it turns into a board. He goes to the person who sold him it and he says "if you weren't Zi'iri, I wouldn't give you your money back...is there someone who buys something where they don't hit/test it with water first?"

So contact with water will break magic. But if sorcerer (I mean a real sorcerer) comes into contact with water (let's say standing in the river, or on the beach, with feet touching the water, or they're swimming) can they perform kishuf or will the water prevent them? What about in rain if it touches them?

Comment: I'm melting! Melting!

Comment: @msh210 I read an essay on the movie with the Jewish lens that said the tin man and straw man are golems, that when she says "there no place like home" it's mirroring prayers for return from the exile, and that the melting witch is taken from Jewish folklore. I would link, but its on an online database. However, hilarious comment!

Comment: There's a looong story (a good one) about (I think) R' Shimon (something like that) and how him and his talmidim fought witches by bringing them out into the rain, and their magic failed. If I can find a source I might post it as an answer.

Comment: Heres a source: https://www.ou.org/life/torah/masechet_sanhedrin_42a48b/ It might not exactly prove what I was saying, so I won't use it as an answer.